# Mongoid embeds_many build nested object twice?

Tags: mongoid, embedded-resource

My models are:

```
class Node
  include Mongoid::Document
end

class PhysicalServer < Node
  embeds_many :network_interfaces
end

class NetworkInterface
  include Mongoid::Document
  embedded_in :physical_server
end
```

If I do:

```
server.network_interfaces.build()
server.save!
```

when I check database, I will see 2 NetworkInterface embedded documents with duplicate ids.

However if I do:

```
server.network_interfaces.create()
```

it'll work correctly (only 1 embedded document created).

Is it a bug in Mongoid, or there is something wrong with my code?
I'm using Ruby1.9.3 + Rails 3.2.9 + Mongoid 3.0.13

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure what the issue is "yet", but I was having the same issue which I have a workaround for the time being.

By doing a forced new lookup in my controller's update action, I was able to get rid of the '$pushAll' creating a duplicate on each call to update. I have a feeling it has something to do with Mongoid's build-up of atomic operations; using a new object simply just removes the 'build' action.

I've created a gist of the issue (hopefully making it possible to re-create both the failing scenario and a workaround: https://gist.github.com/jsmestad/d0103ba0197df9f4505b)